# Looking for best way to do this program

Tags: java

I have two .txt files, first one looks like this :

```
XXXXXXX
XX0X0XX
XX000XX
XXXX0XX
XXXXXXX
```

and second like this :

```
.1..
.111
...1
....
```

First file needs to be seen as a hole made out of zeros and second as a figure make out of ones. I need to write an algorithm that reads both files and checks if "figure" out of second txt file fits into "hole" out of first one. What do you think is the most efficient way to do that ?

I think the best way is to read both files into arrays and then make comparision between arrays, but this is just my first thoughts.

Also final file should look like this :

```
XXXXXXX
XX1X0XX
XX111XX
XXXX1XX
XXXXXXX
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: I think the best way is to read both files into arrays and then make comparision between arrays, but this is just my first thoughts.

Comment: A more efficient way would be to try first, THEN come ask here if you get stuck somewhere. Before asking anything on SO, you need to show us your efforts in helping yourself.

Comment: First try to find A way, any way will do, just make it output the correct result. Then ask how you can refine it.

Comment: And then it would maybe be better asked on Codereview.

Comment: How come the files have different numbers of rows and columns?

Comment: Is there are such thing in java that you could do comparision between the positions of elements in array ?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to:

1. Load the first file in one array
2. Iterate over the second file and compare what you have in the array with what you have read in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can read both files line by line. Pass nth line from both the files to the following method:

```
public static boolean isFit(String a, String b) {
    return a.replace('X', '.').replace('0', '1').equals(b);
}
```

If it return `false` then it is a mis-match otherwise at the end you can say that it is a match.

Comment: If you look closely then you can see that the figure (4x4) is a smaller 2D array than the hole one (5x5) Also it will falsely return false when the hole is bigger than the figure. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small method I threw together that determines whether or not a particular line of the figure matches a particular line in the hole.

```
public static int figureLineFits(char[] figure, char[] hole){

    // Since figure max length per line is 4 and hole is 5 
    // we have to try to match it on either one end or the other.
    char[] hole1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(hole, 0, hole.length-1);
    char[] hole2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(hole, 1, hole.length);

    // We get rid of the extra holes in the hole array.
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(figure[i] == '.'){
            if(hole1[i] == '0') hole1[i] = 'X';
            if(hole2[i] == '0') hole2[i] = 'X';
        }
    }

    // Convert the arrays to Strings because I'm
    // lazy to lookup equivalent array methods.
    String compFigure = figure.toString();
    String compHole1 = hole1.toString();
    String compHole2 = hole2.toString();

    // Replace the 0s with 1s and Xs with .s in the hole strings.
    compHole1.replace('0', '1');
    compHole1.replace('X', '.');
    compHole2.replace('0', '1');
    compHole2.replace('X', '.');

    // Set up some comparison booleans.
    boolean leftComparison = compFigure.equals(compHole1);
    boolean rightComparison = compFigure.equals(compHole2);

    // Do some boolean logic to determine how the figure matches the hole.
    // Will return 3 if figure can be matched on both sides.
    // Will return 1 if figure can be matched on left side.
    // Will return 2 if figure can be matched on right side.
    // Will return 0 if figure doesn't match on either side.
    if(leftComparison && rightComparison) return 3;
    if(leftComparison) return 1;
    if(rightComparison) return 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Then you read the first line of the figure and try to match it with the lines of the hole.
If you can match it (the `figureLineFits` function doesn't return 0) then you can try to match the second line of the figure to the next line of the hole.

If that comparison doesn't return 0 then you have to check if the match is adequate, e.g. if the first line returned 1 and the next one returned 2 then the figure doesn't match. If the first line returned 3 and the second line returned either 1 or 2 then the match is adequate since the "3" means that it matches on both sides.

If you see that the match is not adequate you have to then go back to the first line of the figure and continue to match it on the line after you matched **the first figure line not the consecutive figure lines** since the first figure line might also match the second hole line although the second figure line didn't match the second hole line.

Hopefully this will get your head going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, so basically I need to read my file to array, than convert it to char array and than do that boolean logic ?