# How to convert array to char array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String token1 = "";
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
      token1 = inFile.next();
      temps.add(token1);
    }

    inFile.close();

    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String hole : tempsArray) {
        System.out.println(hole);
    }
```

I read my file to array, but to continue I need to convert this array to char array. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For each `String` in `tempsArray`: `tempArrayString.toCharArray();`. Now, why would you need to convert it to `char[]`?

Comment: I am trying to finish this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036201/looking-for-best-way-to-do-this-program/24037406#24037406

Comment: Let's say your string array is `["hello", "world"]`. What would you want to transform it to?

Comment: Maybe you have your own ideas about it ?

Comment: So your real problem is how to read the data in a text file to create a maze structure type (or similar) in your application to evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to start with `List<char[]>` variable to shorten the code:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
List<char[]> temps = new ArrayList<char[]>();
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    temps.add(inFile.nextLine().toCharArray());
}
inFile.close();
char[][] wholeData = temps.toArray(new char[0][]);
//just to show the data
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(wholeData));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method of string will return an array of char[] the length of the string.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.